# closing concole window results in crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

under my winw7+visual studio 2012 SP4, I write a simple c++ win32 main program Hello world. Upon closing its console, I get crash dialog, both in debug and release modes. Disabled the Unicode, other tries, has not helped. Program is so simple, no bugs. Stepped through every line.

Comment: What you expect from us?

Comment: Can you post your code? Try putting it on pastebin.com

Comment: You can't have both "I get crash dialogs" and "no bugs".

Answer (score -1):

The console will close automatically when main() goes out of scope. You don´t have to call anything to do this

Comment: a simple C++ hello world program that I wrote in my visual studio 2012-sp4. After compiling, building it, I go->debug->start without debugging. I launches cmd.exe window and display the hello World! in it. When I check on the X on the top right, the "windows command processor" pops up with "close the program selected. This is abnormal, it should close the cmd.exe window without "windows command processor" popping up. in "windows command processor", below the "close the program" selection there is another selection "debug the program" that I tried it but got nothing from it.